# Error on importing eli5, Python 3.7, sklearn version 0.19.2'

Tags: scikit-learn

When I import eli5, I get the following error:

```
    157 
    158 def get_cache_token():
--> 159     return ABCMeta._abc_invalidation_counter
    160 
    161
```

> AttributeError: type object 'ABCMeta' has no attribute '_abc_invalidation_counter'

What's this about?

Comment: Seems this is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51659274/3374996

Comment: and this https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/issues/273

Answer (score 1):

For your information, currently eli5 is not supported in python 3.7, fastest solution of the problem is to switch to different version of python, or look for alternative libraries (example: I needed make_moons from eli5, but it have implementation outside it, in sklearn)